# 400 Bad request when using DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: c#, oauth, https, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I am using DotNetOpenAuth to implement OAuth in my local system. Everytime I am getting the following error : +

```
ex.InnerException   {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."} System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}
```

Below is my code snippet

```
  AuthorizationServerDescription authServer = new AuthorizationServerDescription()
{
    TokenEndpoint = new Uri(TOKEN_ENDPOINT),
    AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri(AUTHZ_ENDPOINT),
};

                string[] scopes = new string[] { "Scope" };
                var client = new WebServerClient(authServer , "ClientId", "Client_Secret");


                var token= client.ExchangeUserCredentialForToken("username", "password");
```

When client.ExchangeUserCredentialForToken is called then I am getting error. Couldn't figure out what wrong is happening. What can be the potential reason?

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing the scopes in your request try out adding it the last parameter:

```
client.ExchangeUserCredentialForToken("username", "password", scopes);
```